# Why isn't my anchor tag onclick() sending my data properties to cart even though it's firing my alert?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, anchor

I have dynamically created anchor tags that aren't sending the element properties to a cart as they should be.

I've created a javascript cart program which works fine using anchor elements I've created myself. However, now I'm attempting to use a list of dynamically generated anchor elements to add those items to the cart. The anchor has the same properties as the ones I created, but they aren't being sent to the cart. I know the code for the cart is working because other aspects of it like "remove all" and "total price" are functioning as expected.

When I console.log the click event I can see the anchor's properties that I'm trying to add to cart, and an alert I've added to them fires successfully. I suspect this may have to do with how I'm appending my elements, but can't see where they would be wrong. Any help appreciated!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.slider-for').slick('unslick');
      $('.slider-nav').slick('unslick');
      let bottom = document.getElementById("slider-nav");
      let top = document.getElementById("slider-for");
      let url = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=4';
      fetch(url)
        .then(function(resp) {
          // console.log(resp);
          return resp.json();
        })
        .then(function(data) {
          let users = data.results;
          // console.log(data.results);
          users.forEach(function(element) {

            let childDiv1 = document.createElement('div');

            let childDiv2 = document.createElement('div');


            let myImg1 = document.createElement('img');
            myImg1.src = element.picture.large;
            myImg1.dataset.price = element.location.postcode;
            myImg1.dataset.name = element.name.first

            let myImg2 = document.createElement('img');
            myImg2.src = element.picture.medium;


            let myTag = document.createElement('a');
            myTag.href = '#';
            myTag.addEventListener('click', alertFunction);
            myTag.className = 'add';
            myTag.id = 'add';
            myTag.title = 'click to add to cart'
            myTag.dataset.price = element.location.price;
            myTag.dataset.name = element.name.first

            childDiv1.appendChild(myImg1);
            myTag.appendChild(childDiv1);
            let newPics1 = top.appendChild(myTag);
            // console.log(newPics1);

            childDiv2.appendChild(myImg2);
            let newPics2 = bottom.appendChild(childDiv2);


      })
      $('.slick-for').slick('slickAdd');
      $('.slider-for').slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: false,
        fade: true,
        asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
      });
      $('.slick-nav').slick('slickAdd');
      $('.slider-nav').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        asNavFor: '.slider-for',
        dots: true,
        centerMode: true,
        focusOnSelect: true
      });

    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    })

});
```

I expect to click on an image nested in an anchor tag and have the anchor element properties sent to a cart. I'm clicking on the image and the console shows it's the correct image but it's not being sent to cart.

Comment: Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that could be easily reproduced, in a code sharing platform like codepen or jsfiddle? For example, I cannot see where is the actual method that should be run on image click, and there is no implementation for the alertFunction specified. Providing this information might help us with tracking down the reason for your problems.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - here is the code, althought it's not functioning here, I think everything is included....https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLYbWm

Comment: I'm having trouble minimalizing and completing the code in codepen to work, but I've attempted to label everything with comments as clearly as possible. It's basically just a carousel showing an image nested in an anchor tag. Onclick it should send some of the properties to an ul, which should show in a cart window. I can see the anchor properties when I onclick in the console, but for whatever reason it's not actually going to the cart as hoped for.

Comment: Additionally, when I click on the anchor, I noticed that the <li> that should be created to get the properties to the cart don't get created when I inspect elements. Perhaps my cart functions aren't capturing this click somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody else is experiencing this issue, here's the answer that I found.

I was using jQuery with a "click" targeted on the dynamic anchor elements that I was creating.

I think this is because I was using functions containing "this" keyword, affecting the ability of my anchors to be recognized. To allow your anchors to be recognized, target the container that your element is appended to (or the next parent element that wasn't dynamic if you've got nested elements) and use the following jQuery code:

```
$("firstNonDynamicParentElementId").on("click", "a.class", function() {
    'whatever your function does goes here'
};
```

In my case I replaced this code with the above and it worked perfectly:

```
$(".add").click(function(event) {
    'whatever your function does goes here'
};
```